# Undo button animation by clicking another button but only if the animation has been played

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jsfiddle

So I have a simple button animation. When you click button1 another button (button2) animates in and takes its place and button1 is animated away and hidden.

I also have a drop-down selection above the button. When you click the drop-down I need it to undo the animation (Play again backwards) so that button1 shows again and button 2 is hidden. But ONLY if button2 is showing should it "undo" the animation by clicking the drop-down.

I simplified the code 

## JS FIDDLE.

I posted a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41977954/animate-on-button-click-than-if-that-button-is-clicked-revert-animation-if-sep) but got no replies because i was making it too complicated. I hope this is more clear and helps by simplifying things.

Thanks guys!

**Html**

```
<div class="wrap">
  <select class="options">
    <option value="option1">Volvo</option>
    <option value="option2">Saab</option>
    <option value="option3">Fiat</option>
  </select>

  <div class="btn-wrap">
    <button class="btn1">
     Add to cart
    </button>
    <button class="btn2">
     Checkout
    </button>
  </div>

</div>
```

**Css**

```
.wrap{
  width:100%;
  height: 300px;
  background: gray;
}

.btn-wrap{
  position:relative;
  background:green;
  max-width;200px;
  width:200px;
  height:40px;
  overflow:hidden;
  margin:4%;
}
button{
  width:200px;
  height:40px;
  border:0px;
  outline:none;
  color:white;
  font-size:14px;
  font-weight:bold;
  display:inline-block;
  cursor:pointer;
}

.btn1{
  background-color:blue;
}
.btn2{
  background-color:red;
}

.options{
  width:200px;
  height:50px;
  background:white;
  margin:7%;
  border:0px;
  text-indent:20px;
}
```

**JS**

```
$(".btn-wrap").click(function() {

  $('.btn1').css('position', 'relative').animate ( { top:'-40px' }  );
  $('.btn2').css('position', 'relative').animate ( { top:'-40px' }  );

});
```

Comment: "I posted a similar question but got no replies because i was making it too complicated. I hope this is more clear." -- Why not simply edit **that** question to be more clear?

Comment: Because if i edit a question that was asked over a day ago no one would know i edited it and it would not gain any attention. Plus adding this additional information onto my old post would just make my old post extra large and scare anyone away from helping.

Comment: Its not the same question but will solve both problems for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand, all you had to do is make an event that checks whether or not `.option` was clicked on or not.

[Demo](http://codepen.io/thejseffect/pen/wgmqXM)

JS

```
let undo = false;

$(".btn-wrap").click(function() {
    if(undo == false) {
        $('.btn1').css('position', 'relative').animate ( { top:'-40px' }  );
        $('.btn2').css('position', 'relative').animate ( { top:'-40px' }  );

        undo = true;
    }
});

$(".options").on("click", function() {
    $('.btn1').css('position', 'relative').animate ( { top:'0px' }  );
    $('.btn2').css('position', 'relative').animate ( { top:'20px' }  );

    undo = false;
})
```

Comment: Yeah  i guess i needed the "If" statment.

The problem im having now I guess is i need the button animation to still work even if its been reset by clicking on the drop down.

Comment: Thanks soooo much! This is perfect.